# In Github when creating github.io profile what the difference of .md .html .rmd files?

Tags: html, github, markdown

I'm trying to create a `github.io` profile.

May I know the difference between of .md .html .rmd files?

For example, I see the same file name with different filetypes like
`Readme.md` vs `Readme.html`    `XXX.rmd` vs `XXX.html`

Comment: Still searching for a good source for you before I put this as an answer - but in short github.io (aka Github pages) uses software called Jekyll to gather html (along with css) files to build a website (a website usually being described by html and css files). Markdown files (`.md` or `.rmd` for the related R-markdown) are files used on github and elsewhere to generate documentation and are also read by Jekyll to build html for additional pages for the generated website.

Comment: Thank you @SamBob I hardly understand this :) — to make it simple, may I know if I create only HTML files and upload them to GitHub, can I create a profile? Do I have to create other files also?

Comment: You don't need to use markdown files - they can be optionally used instead of html (though they are easier to write then html for generating documentation). The instructions here: http://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages/ show you how to make a github pages site with html. Stop when you get to the section `Using Jekyll with GitHub Pages` as that is where using markdown instead of or alongside html is introduced and you don't need to use it!

Comment: If you do want to try creating markdown files in future instead of html https://stackedit.io/ is a useful tool for creating it.

Comment:  Thanks a heap @SamBob . I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, I've summarised these comments as an answer, and I'd appreciate it if you could accept it as the answer if this was helpful to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

github.io (aka Github pages) can create a website from either

- `html` with optional `css`
- Markdown files (`.md` and `.rmd`)
- A combination of the above

It uses a set of tools called `Jekyll` and `kramdown` to translate markdown files into html to be displayed as part of the website.

Markdown files are a file format generally used for producing documentation in github on similar websites, and has a mopre streamlined syntax for that purpose than html. You can try it out at https://stackedit.io

The use of markdown for Github Pages is however completely optional and you may use only html if you wish. You can follow the guide at  https://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages show you how to make a github pages site with html. Stop when you get to the section Using Jekyll with GitHub Pages if you don't wish to incorporate any markdown.